# In Java-8 Locale Object convert to old ISO in some Language code. How can i fix this issue without update Java version?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

Like when i take input (he-IL) then output comes like "iw_IL". But i do not want this convert to old iso.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale locale = getLocaleIn("he-IL");
    System.out.println(locale.toString());
}
private static Locale getLocaleIn(String langCode) {
    LocaleCode code = LocaleCode.getByCodeIgnoreCase(langCode);
    Locale locale = code.toLocale();
    return locale;
}
```

OutPut:
**iw_IL**,
Expected Output:
**he-IL**

**Main Problem in Here, In Java Locale.Class:**
[image]

***Finally I Want an Locale Object without Converting to old ISO.***

Comment: What is LocaleCode ?

Comment: its an another libriry to fecth keyword.

Comment: by default Local class take data and in constructor it convert iso to old iso

Comment: IMHO the LocaleCode is the problem

Comment: What is not correct ist the input he-IL. This should be he_IL

Comment: No...both are same because i use ignore case for thats way i used in there localeCode

Comment: for input (he-IL) output is (iw_IL) also

Comment: @SimonMartinelli `LocaleCode` is not responsible. But this distraction demonstrates, why we should try to minimize examples…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid non-standard 3rd party classes in problem descriptions, especially when they do not contribute to the problem at all.

We can simply use

```java
Locale locale = new Locale("he", "IL");
System.out.println(locale.toString());
locale = new Locale("iw", "IL");
System.out.println(locale.toString());
```

and get

```
iw_IL
iw_IL
```

under JDK 8, which is in line with [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

> This constructor accepts both the old codes ("iw", "ji", and "in") and the new codes ("he", "yi", and "id"), but all other API on Locale will return only the OLD codes.

This has changed [with JDK 17](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)):

> Obsolete ISO 639 codes ("iw", "ji", and "in") are mapped to their current forms.

and running the same example program with JDK 17 accordingly now prints

```
he_IL
he_IL
```

So the cleanest and probably the only solution to your issue would be updating the Java version. Any patch forcing `Locale` to return the new code in older versions may cause compatibility problems with other components of the runtime relying on the old behavior.